# UITableView checking for detail view

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, datasource, detailview

I don't speak english very well so I hope that you understand.

I have to control my source data(an array of array from a csv) to see if it have the same element double, if this is true I want to insert only one of this in my `List` of `TableView`, but I have to store this, cause I need to know which of this element in the list must visualize a detail view. If the element is double in the source data I have to show the detail view, else nothing.

I tried a bit of method but I haven't found the solution, yet.

This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

NSMutableArray *listaNonOrdinata = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
self.navigationItem.title = @"Tipologia";

NSString *fileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Lista1" ofType:@"csv"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
record = [fileString csvRows];

dettaglio = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
id doppio = nil;

for (int i=1; i < record.count; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < listaNonOrdinata.count; j++) {
        doppio = [[record objectAtIndex:i] firstObjectCommonWithArray:listaNonOrdinata];
        if (doppio == nil) {
            [dettaglio addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
        } else {
            [dettaglio addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
        }
    }
    if (doppio == nil) {
        [listaNonOrdinata addObject:[[record objectAtIndex:i]objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
}

//Ordino array in ordine alfabetico
lista = [[NSArray alloc]init];
lista = [listaNonOrdinata sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

[listaNonOrdinata release];
// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

Can everyone help me?
Thanks.

**I'VE FOUND THE SOLUTION:**
I had badly configured the array, now it works fine!